# My Navigation bar is not responsive on mobile devices of max-width 480px

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a custom drop-down navigation bar that is responsive to screens above 480 px. I have created a hidden menu icon whereby below 480px, the icon is displayed and when it is clicked the navigation bar should display including the drop-down list. Below 480 px, the icon displays well but after clicking it,the drop-down list does not display.I am using HTML5 and CSS3.

```css
/*Styles the background-color of an active link*/
    .menu ul .active{
     color: #ffffff;
     background: #red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 20%, green); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(red 20%, green); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(red 20%, green); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
        background: linear-gradient(red 20%, green); /* Standard syntax */
        background: linear-gradient(red 20%, green); /* Standard syntax */
    }
    
    
    .navbar{
     width:100%;
     max-width:1000px;
     text-align:center;
     margin-top:-8px;
     margin-bottom:60px;
     margin-left:160px;
    }
    
    .menu ul{
     /*Removes bullets*/
     list-style:none;
    }
    
    /*Styles each list within ul*/
    .menu ul li{
     background-color:green;
     border:1px solid #ffffff;
     width:100%;
     max-width:173px;
     height:35px;
     line-height:35px;
     margin:auto;
     text-align:center;
     /*Makes the list dispaly in a horizontal maneer*/
     float:left;
     position: relative;
     border-radius:8px;
     font: 15px;
     font-weight:regular;
    }
    
    .menu ul li a{
     text-decoration:none;
     color:white;
     display:block;
    }
    
    
    .menu ul li a:hover{
     background-color:red;
     border-radius:8px;
    }
    
    .menu ul ul{
     position:absolute;
     margin-left:-40px;
     display:none;
    }
    
    .menu ul li:hover >ul{
     display:block;
    }
    
    .menu ul ul ul{
     width:100%;
     margin-left:134px;
     top:0px;
    }
    
    /*Display the drop-down on hover*/
    /*+ selecctor styles every element that are placed immediately after another element */
    .menu ul li a:hover + .menu ul li ul, .menu ul li ul:hover{
     display:block;
    }
    
    /*Hide Checkbox*/
    input[type=checkbox]{
     display:none;
    }
    
    /*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
    /*We select checkbox and then use selector column checked to make sure that the checkbox is checked*/
    /*~ selects everything that is beneath element on the left shoul be styled with CSS style within the curly bracket*/
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .list{
     display:block;
    }
    
    /*Styles the menu-label according to its class*/
    .show-menu{
     font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#fff;
     background: #19c589;
     text-align:center;
     padding:10px 0;
     display:none;
    }
    
    
    /*Responsive styles*/
    @media screen and (max-width:480px){
     /*Make drop-down links appear inline*/
     .menu ul{
      position:static;
      display: none;
     }
     
     /*Create vertical spacing*/
     .menu ul li{
      margin-bottom:1px;
     }
     
     /*Make all menu links full width*/
     .menu ul li, .menu li a{
      width:100%;
     }
     
     .show-menu{
      display:block;
     }
     body{
      background-image:none;
     }
    
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <!-- Clicking on the label will check the checkbox because for and id of checkbox are the same-->
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"> Menu </label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu">
    
    
    <div class="navbar">
     <div class="menu">
      <ul class ="list">
       <li class="active">  Home </li>
       <li> <a href="humanities.html"> Humanities <span class="arrow">&#9660; </span> </a>
        <ul>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Music </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Linguistics </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Penology  </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Anthropology </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Sociology <span class="arrow">  &rang;</span></a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Psychology</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Counselling </a></li>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> C.M.D </a></li>
          </ul> 
         </li>  
         
        </ul>
        
        
        
       </li>
       <li> <a href="education.html"> Education <span class="arrow">&#9660; </span> </a>
        <ul>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> E.C.D.E </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Science </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Arts with Edu </a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Swahili </a></li>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Psychology </a></li>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Sociology of Ed. </a></li>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Liberal Ed. </a></li>
          </ul> 
         </li>  
         
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li> <a href="eng.html"> Engineering <span class="arrow">&#9660; </span> </a>
        <ul>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Electrical </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Civil & Structural </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Aeronautical </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Chemical </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#"rel="nofollow" > Mechanical </a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Industrial </a></li>
           <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Automotive </a></li>
          </ul> 
         </li>  
         
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li> <a href="contact.php" rel="nofollow"> Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      
     </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle so we can try help you more easy. It seems is something you do to the menu that makes it break in the media query. Just test remove some stuff from the media query till it works.

Comment: @MrLister I posted the whole code am using,,,

Comment: @Medda86 How do I go about jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem is that your `#show-menu` checkbox doesn't do anything, so all you need to so is add the line

```css
  #show-menu:checked ~ .navbar .menu ul {display: block;}
```

to your CSS. Then a click on the big menu button will do the trick. No need for extra JavaScript routines.

Tip: run the snippet in full page mode, so that you can make the window narrow enough.

```css
/*Styles the background-color of an active link*/

.menu ul .active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 20%, green);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red 20%, green);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red 20%, green);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(red 20%, green);
  /* Standard syntax */
  background: linear-gradient(red 20%, green);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}

.menu ul {
  /*Removes bullets*/
  list-style: none;
}


/*Styles each list within ul*/

.menu ul li {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 173px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  /*Makes the list dispaly in a horizontal maneer*/
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font: 15px;
  font-weight: regular;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -40px;
  display: none;
}

.menu ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu ul ul ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 134px;
  top: 0px;
}


/*Display the drop-down on hover*/


/*+ selecctor styles every element that are placed immediately after another element */

.menu ul li a:hover+.menu ul li ul,
.menu ul li ul:hover {
  display: block;
}


/*Hide Checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}


/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/


/*We select checkbox and then use selector column checked to make sure that the checkbox is checked*/


/*~ selects everything that is beneath element on the left shoul be styled with CSS style within the curly bracket*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.list {
  display: block;
}


/*Styles the menu-label according to its class*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}


/*Responsive styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /*Make drop-down links appear inline*/
  .menu ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  .menu ul li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  .menu ul li,
  .menu li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  body {
    background-image: none;
    margin-top:70px; /* ML remove this line; this is a patch for the full screen snippet problem */
  }

  #show-menu:checked ~ .navbar .menu ul {display: block;}
}
```

```html
<!-- Clicking on the label will check the checkbox because for and id of checkbox are the same-->
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"> Menu </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu">


<div class="navbar">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="active"> Home </li>
      <li> <a href="humanities.html"> Humanities <span class="arrow">&#9660; </span> </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Music </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Linguistics </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Penology  </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Anthropology </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Sociology <span class="arrow">  &rang;</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Psychology</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Counselling </a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> C.M.D </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>



      </li>
      <li> <a href="education.html"> Education <span class="arrow">&#9660; </span> </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> E.C.D.E </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Science </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Arts with Edu </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Swahili </a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Psychology </a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Sociology of Ed. </a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Liberal Ed. </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="eng.html"> Engineering <span class="arrow">&#9660; </span> </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Electrical </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Civil & Structural </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Aeronautical </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Chemical </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Mechanical </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Industrial </a></li>
              <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow"> Automotive </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="contact.php" rel="nofollow"> Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would require a click event(JavaScript) to your menu button. Here is the code I wrote in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/capozzic1/qacyh592/4/. To run that fiddle, first select the middle part of the page to resize the html page(which is on the right lower hand side) to the size of a mobile device, then click "Run" on the upper left, then click on the large menu button in the HTML to see the rest of the nav bar links show.

Also, if you click the menu bar again while it is shown, it will go back to display none.

If you add this script:

```
var menuBtn = document.querySelector(".show-menu");
var menu = document.querySelector(".menu ul");
menuBtn.onclick = function(){

if (menu.style.display == "none") { 
    menu.style.display = "block";
} else { 
    menu.style.display = "none";
}


}
```

Then clicking on the menu button should make the rest of your navbar appear. You can add this script putting it into a file named script.js, then, in your html, in the lower part of the body, put

```
"<script src="script.js"></script>"
```